# Binning the data of one cell in a data frame using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below:

|  | class 1 | class 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | M | NaN |
| 1 | 17245 | NaN |
| 2 | graduate | Bach |

I want to use pd.cut() function and bin the data 17245 to 15000-25000. How do I do it?

Comment: isn't 17425 already in between 15000-25000? Can you stare more clearly what exactly is the requirement? NB `pd.cut` doc can help you.

Comment: I want to update the cell value from 17245 to 15000-25000 using pd.cut. Not sure how to select that one cell and make changes.

Comment: [This](https://predictivehacks.com/how-to-create-bins-in-python-using-pandas/) is probably what you need. Although your data is trange: why does class1 contain different types of data? how do you want to bin strings?

Comment: I just want to bin that one cell, not the entire column. It has different types of data because that column defines the class.